# Small fix on expansion tile with json data

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have a complex json. Using it must create expansion tiles. Imagine that in categories there are subcategories. In subcategories also have sub-sub categories. But model is same. I created that, but in `Entry.fromJson()` method need a small fix on children. I can't get child subcategories of categories. Please not use any plugin like `flutter_treeview` . Please help. Sample json string is in below:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"parent 1","subcategories":[{"id":11,"name":"cat news 1 of 1","subcategories":[]}]},{"id":2,"name":"parent 2","subcategories":[{"id":22,"name":"cat news 1 of 2","subcategories":[]}]},{"id":3,"name":"parent 3","subcategories":[]}]
```

The flutter code shown below:

```
class SubcategoryPage2 extends StatefulWidget {
  const SubcategoryPage2({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SubcategoryPage2State createState() => _SubcategoryPage2State();
}

class _SubcategoryPage2State extends State<SubcategoryPage2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('2nd test')),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: jsonDecode(sampleJson)[0].length,
        itemBuilder: (context, int index) =>
            EntryItem(Entry.fromJson(jsonDecode(sampleJson)[index])),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Entry {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final List<Entry> children;
  Entry(
      {required this.id, required this.name, this.children = const <Entry>[]});

  factory Entry.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Entry(
        id: json['id'],
        name: json['name'],
        children: List<Entry>.from(json['subcategories'])
        );
  }
}
class EntryItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final Entry entry;
  const EntryItem(this.entry, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Widget _buildTiles(Entry root) {
    if (root.children.isEmpty) {
      return ListTile(title: Text(root.name));
    }
    return ExpansionTile(
      key: PageStorageKey<Entry>(root),
      title: Text(root.name),
      children: root.children.map(_buildTiles).toList(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildTiles(entry);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is it exactly that you want?..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to our turkish friend Huseyin Bedir. We solved the problem. Now we can go infinitely in ExpansionTiles using json. Solution is on my github repository [Github repo](https://github.com/Martyhacker/complex-category)[image: Result shown in image]